# Background music in my app doesn't start

Tags: android

I'm trying to add background music to my app.
I read a lot of examples, but I have always the same problem. The music doesn't start, and I have no error message.

I have a class that menages the background music

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
       player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);
        player.start();
}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
}

protected void onNewIntent() {
    player.pause();
}
}
```

And, in my main class, inside the onCreate method, I use

```
 Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
            startService(svc);
```

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.giocobambini"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.giocobambini.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>   

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.giocobambini.BackgroundSoundService"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_background_sound_service" >
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Maybe the problem is minSdkVersion="8"!! Maybe for minSdkVersion 8 background music is not supported?

Comment: Before `player.start();` try adding `player.prepare();`.

Comment: No, it still doesn't start :(

Comment: I think can't call the BackgroundSoundService  class.
In the onCreate method of the BackgroundSoundService  class, i tried to write something in a textview. But i could't, this means that from  my main class i'm not able to call the BackgroundSoundService class!!!

Comment: Services don't have a findViewById() because they have no UI. This means that onNewIntent() does not actually exist. Also, I'd suggest moving your MediaPlayer setup to `onStart()` ,double checking to see you actually have the resource & cleaning your project, and throwing some log statements to see if your service is in fact being started and destroyed.

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali : Override `public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {...}` and move your `player` code in to it.

Comment: @Squonk

this way???
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{   
  
 player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
 player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
 player.setVolume(100,100);
 player.start();
   
    return START_STICKY;
}

Comment: @A--C

I already tried it, but it doens't start

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali : Yes.

Comment: Post your manifest file..

Comment: @rahul kapoor  
I can't answer in the forum, because of the forum rules. So i have to write it here, but my manifest file has more characters then how many are allowed, so i post only the things i suppose you want to see. BackgroundSoundService is my class with the music player
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.giocobambini.BackgroundSoundService"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_background_sound_service" >
        </activity>

Comment: You can edit your question, and add your manifest file. Its not against the forum rules. How people can see Check your problem with complete code?

Comment: @rahul kapoor sorry, you are right, i tried to post my manifest file by answering to my own question, but i was told i couldn't do it. I didnt' think about editing my first post.
Anyway, now i did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **service** should be declared with the android manifest file before starting **service**. This process will be done within  tags as follows.

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<service android:name="BackgroundSoundService"  android:enabled="true"></service>
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works!
That was the problem.
Thank everybody :D

Comment: Now i have problem stopping the music when the user switch to another app.
By reading on the internetm I thought it was enough doing: public void onPause(){
 player.stop();
  player.release();
}

Comment: Google once again. And try something